# latex, how to put superscript and link to URL downpage

Tags: footnotes, links

In a document, how do we do this:

[image]

i.e. how to put a superscript and then link it to a link as shown in the diagram?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question? It seems that all you need is a `\footnote` with an `\url` from, for example, the `url` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}    

\vspace*{\fill}

text\footnote{\url{www.stackexchange.com}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\vspace*{\fill}` line was just to push the text to the bottom of the page for the example; you don't need this in your document.

Comment: when do we use footnote, why don't we just provide it as a reference?

Comment: @user1774937 I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: I've seen in many research papers that they use footnote, I'm just trying to google around but did not find a good explanation. When do we use footnote?

Comment: @user1774937 I am not friend of using footnotes, as Bringhurst says (p.68 of his Elements): "Footnotes are the very emblem of fussiness"; however (paraphrasing Bringhurst), short, infrequent footnotes might be acceptable. When to use a footnote? Some say that when  you need to comment on or cite a reference for a designated part of the text. My recommendation is, however, if possible, never to use them. This can be very debatable and a comment is clearly not the place to discuss this in depth.

Comment: why we need \vspace*{\fill} ? I see by default the text goes to the bottom of the page, that's the purpose of footnote package - right? Would be awesome to know why we need to deploy the vspace command.